# How to tell the browser that a password input is not a form or login?

Tags: html, input, passwords

I have an app where you can configure server files. One server file is the users one, that contains the hashed password. The admin can create all the users he wants in the website form.

I'm using a simple `input` with `type="password"` so the admin can benefit of native browser password handling (like the "show password" button on IE11 or showing the last written letter on smartphones), then the password is hashed and sent to the server. The problem here is that the browser asks to save the password, autofill it and such. I don't want the `autocomplete=off` hack because some browsers override it. I would like to know a way to tell the browser that the password is not an input to remember but just a hidden text, like a textbox or whatever.

I can create a simple input and overlay a password input, and also I can add a *password* font that will replace all letters for dots, but, as I said, I prefer to keep browser password handling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
`autocomplete="new-password"`

From reading around this should work, however there is some other crude methods which may also work if this doesn't.

Check out this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15917221/7122588

Comment: Too bad is only for Chrome and FF, but is exactly was I was asking for. Now I need IE11 and I'm done. Going to wait for another reply just in case. +1 this :P

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález did you check out the other suggestions in that topic. Although they are crude they might work for IE.

Comment: Yes. Looking for the `readonly` one, but is "hacky" too. I guess I can't do nothing without any hack. F***ing IE :-/